Did Israeli officials confirm any sort of attack directly on Iranian territory?
BBC has this:

But in Israel there was criticism over the limited scope of the attack.
The far-right national security minister, Itamar Ben Gvir, posted on social media one word: "Lame."
The opposition leader, Yair Lapid, has accused Ben Gvir of damaging Israel by exposing it to ridicule.

Interestingly:

Jonathan Conricus, a former IDF spokesman, said: "Iran seeks to return to the shadows and is downplaying the Israeli strike on the strategic city of Isfahan, but I think they've gotten the message: Israel can penetrate Iranian defences and strike wherever it wants."

Conricus was until recently (a few months ago at least) an IDF spokesman. I'm not sure when he retired from that job. (Apparently he's with the Foundation for the Defense of Democracies now, though. -- Apparently in January.)
Did Israel officially acknowledge any sort of attack on Iran in its own territory?

Many comments deleted - please reserve comments for requesting clarification from the author, or for constructive criticism. If you would like to answer, please use the 'Your Answer' box.

Israel adheres to the policy of deliberate ambiguity, neither confirming nor denying such actions, but usually ensuring that it is well known who is behind them.
This case is no exception:

The Israel Defense Forces told CNN that they "do not have a comment at this time."[46] A senior United States official confirmed that Israel had conducted a strike and noted that the US was notified by Israel in advance of the operation.[9] An Iranian official told Reuters that the explosions were due to the activation of Iran's air defense systems, and added that there had been no missile attack on Iran.[12]

In other words, Israel treats it as a common knowledge, and as such it makes an object of open discussion, but one shouldn't hold one's breath expecting an official statement or a government official answering to a point-blank question "yes, we did it".
Another approach is communicating through "unnamed officials":

Israel carried out a strike on Iran early Friday in retaliation for a barrage of missiles and drones launched last weekend, an Israeli official said. It was not clear what damage the apparently limited strike caused in central Iran, but the official — who spoke on the condition of anonymity to discuss sensitive military matters — said it was intended to signal to Iran that Israel has the ability to strike inside the country. Secretary of State Antony Blinken declined to comment on whether Washington was warned about the strike, but he emphasized that “the United States has not been involved in any offensive operations.”

For the moments of writing the latest update from Al-Jazeera is:

Israel has not commented on the attacks yet.
[...]
Israel has not claimed responsibility for the attack, and the military has not commented either.
According to a report by The Washington Post, quoting an Israeli official, the strike was intended to signal to Iran that Israel has the ability to reach Iran with its weapons, and it was “carefully calibrated”.



Did Israel officially acknowledge any sort of attack on Iran in its own territory?

On May 5th, Transportation Minister Miri Regev acknowledged Israel's retaliation for Iran's massive attack on Israel. A Transportation Minister is not part of the War Cabinet, but it's an official.
Some sources:

https://www.ynetnews.com/article/hkw11ui4mr
https://www.jpost.com/israel-news/politics-and-diplomacy/article-799866
https://www.iranintl.com/en/202405057382


Despite the comments by former officials, it seems nobody presently in office has been explicit about it... except anonymously and to Western media, at least as of a couple of hours ago, when Reuters wrote this:

Israeli media cited reports from the New York Times and the Washington Post, which quoted unnamed Israeli officials as confirming Israel was behind the attack, but did not report official confirmation of their own.

The  same piece mentions that

Israel has never acknowledged that it was behind the strike on April 1.

This is unlike what Trump did in re Soleimani. Also unlike what the IDF has sometimes done in re Syria, e.g. confirming in 2020 having struck the "Headquarters of the Syrian Armed Forces 7th Division", among 50 targets. But indeed the policy on discussing any such events deep inside Iran has been far more reserved.

Regarding the attitudes to acknowledging such events: Why do the United States openly acknowledge targeted assassinations?

@FourLegsGoodTwoLegsBad: FWTW, the most recent upvoted answer there says "Deterrence only works if the people you are deterring know you are trying to deter them." But explicit statements are apparently not all that needed for that. YMMV. (I see you also had doubt about that answer, in a comment there.)

The archetypal case here is the Israeli response to the Munich massacre, which aimed at publicly punishing the perpetrators, while maintaining deniability. The urban legend also says that Vanunu was deliberately allowed to disclose the Israeli nuclear program.

Confirming an attack in Syria which is against Syrian military is a non-issue - there's an existing state of war between the countries. However, Israel rarely, if at all, confirms attacks against Iranian targets in Syria.
